# Error Spring Boot 2

Tags: java

Hola amigos tengo un procedimiento almacenado en sql server 2014:

create database db_spring_2

use db_spring_2

create table tb_usuario(
id_usuario int primary key identity(1,1),
nombre varchar(200),
apellidopat varchar(200),
apellidomat varchar(200),
email varchar(200) unique,
foto_url varchar(500)
)

insert into tb_usuario values('Marcos','Marcos','MAr','mar@gmail.com', '123.jpg')

go
alter proc usp_usuario 
as
begin
select nombre from tb_usuario
end

que estoy llamando de en un proyecto de Spring boot 2 pero me sale este error:

```js
019-08-21 19:51:31.284 ERROR 6752 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The column name id_usuario is not valid.
2019-08-21 19:51:31.292 ERROR 6752 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name id_usuario is not valid.
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:206) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar:na]
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.findColumn(SQLServerResultSet.java:686) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar:na]
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getInt(SQLServerResultSet.java:2337) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getInt(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
 at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
 at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
 at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
 at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
 at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
 at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:793) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:718) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
```

Aca el metodo donde llamo el procedimiento almacenado

```js
package com.example.demo.repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.entity.Usuarios;

@Repository
public interface IUsuarioRepository extends CrudRepository<Usuarios, Integer>{

 @Query(value = "exec usp_usuario" , nativeQuery=true )
 public List<Usuarios> getUsuarios();
}
```

Mi interface del Servicio

```js
package com.example.demo.repository;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.demo.entity.Usuarios;

public interface IUsuarioService {

 public List<Usuarios> getUsuarios();
}
```

Y mi servicio

```js
package com.example.demo.services;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.demo.entity.Usuarios;
import com.example.demo.repository.IUsuarioRepository;
import com.example.demo.repository.IUsuarioService;

@Transactional
@Service
public class UusuarioServices implements IUsuarioService {

 @Autowired
 private IUsuarioRepository usuarioR;
 
 @Override
 public List<Usuarios> getUsuarios() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return usuarioR.getUsuarios();
 }

}
```

---

el error me sale cuando realizo una peticion get

```js
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/usuario")
public class UsuarioController {
 
 @Autowired
 private IUsuarioService usuarioS;
 
 @GetMapping("/listadoUsuario")
 public List<Usuarios> getUsuario(){
  return usuarioS.getUsuarios();
 }

}
```

lo raro es que me sale bien todo correcto cuando en el procedimiento almacenado hago 
un select * from

go
alter proc usp_usuario 
as
begin
select * from tb_usuario
end

Answer (score 0):

Tu error está en el stored procedure. Mas precisamente en el insert. Cambia esta linea:

```
insert into tb_usuario values('Marcos','Marcos','MAr','mar@gmail.com', '123.jpg')
```

por esta otra:

```
insert into tb_usuario(nombre, apellidopat, apellidomat, email, foto_url) values('Marcos','Marcos','MAr','mar@gmail.com', '123.jpg')
```

dado que cuando haces un insert sin mencionar los campos que vas a insertar, por default, se interpretan TODOS los campos de la tabla y te estaría faltando el id_usuario que es justamente lo que te está indicando el error que mostras en tu pregunta. 
Escribiendo el insert como yo te indico, el campo id_usuario no se especifica, entonces se interpreta que no lo querés insertar y se utiliza el autonumerico definido en el create de la tabla. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Ya hice la prueba pero me sale mal

Comment: ya que cuando realizo un get a mi controller

Comment: @Alex que error te dá cuando cambias el insert como yo te puse?

Comment: ningun error el error me sale cuando hago la peticion get

Comment: lo que sospechoso es que cuando en el procedimiento almacenado pongo un select * from tb_usuario me sale todo ok me devuelve todos los valores pero cuando hago un select nombre from tb_usuario me sale ese error